# ¿Cómo iterar campo Cursor de consulta Oracle en PHP?

Tags: oracle-11g, php7

Espero me puedan colaborar, necesito obtener los datos de una consulta SQL en Oracle 11g, la cual uno de sus campos es tipo cursor, esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT m.nombre, m.icono, (CURSOR(SELECT p.nombre nombre_permiso, p.url
                                FROM permiso p 
                                WHERE p.fk_menu = m.pk_menu 
                                AND p.estado = 'A'
                                ORDER BY p.orden)) permisos FROM menu m WHERE m.estado = 'A' ORDER BY orden;
```

Cuando lo ejecuto con PHP el campo **nombre_permiso** me aparece como tipo ResourceId pero debería darme los campos que contiene, supongo que es así por el tipo de campo, el código PHP que uso es el siguiente:

```
$sql = "DECLARE
                    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
                BEGIN
                    OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT m.nombre, m.icono, (CURSOR(SELECT p.nombre nombre_permiso, p.url
                                                      FROM permiso p 
                                                      WHERE p.fk_menu = m.pk_menu 
                                                      AND p.estado = 'A'
                                                      ORDER BY p.orden)) permisos
                    FROM menu m
                    WHERE m.estado = 'A'
                    ORDER BY orden;

                    :cursor := my_cursor;
                END; ";

        $conn = $this->db->conn_id;
        $curs = oci_new_cursor($conn);
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":cursor", $curs, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
        oci_execute($stid);

        oci_execute($curs);
        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($curs, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) 
        {
            var_dump($row);
        }

        oci_free_statement($stid);
        oci_free_statement($curs);
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué muestra el `var_dump` exactamente? Podría ser útil que pusieras un ejemplo de su resultado [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/194103/edit).

Comment: El var_dump del campo muestra:                                               array(3) { ["NOMBRE"]=> string(16) "Parametrización" 
   ["ICONO"]=> string(11) "fa fa-gears" 
   ["PERMISOS"]=> resource(46) of type (oci8 statement) 
   } 
array(3) { ["NOMBRE"]=> string(24) "Gestión de información" 
   ["ICONO"]=> string(10) "fa-sitemap" 
   ["PERMISOS"]=> resource(47) of type (oci8 statement) 
  }